# Can the Xcode linker remove unused code when you import a Swift package?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

Let's say you import a Swift package from which you only need a tiny piece (for example a single method from the [Swift Algorithms package](https://swift.org/blog/swift-algorithms/))

It seems the linker doesn't optimize away all the other methods - for a [simple example project](https://github.com/ralfebert/FoodChoiceExample/tree/chunks-algorithm) only using `chunks(ofCount:)` from the Swift Algorithms package the binary size grew from 193 KB to 3,9 MB. So it seems getting only a tiny piece of a large package is a bad idea if you care about app binary size.

Is there a better way to reduce the resulting app binary size besides removing the Swift package and copying the actually needed source files to your own project?

Comment: What did your experimentation suggest might be the answer?

Comment: It seems not to optimize -> updated the question.

Comment: No, you cannot use only a part of a library. How would work? A library is a file and you cannot just include a part of that file in your binary.

Comment: Instead of import a full package, create an empty swift file, and copy just the needed codes from the library.

Comment: yes, copying the source file obviously works, and still, I am looking for a better way. In theory the linker could only link symbols that are needed or optimize away symbols not needed at all.

Comment: I agree with your experimental results (thank you for posting the example!). I guess I don't see why this is an issue. However, you could file an enhancement request with Apple!

Comment: Since Swift Packages are compiled from source (at least in this example), why can’t the linker optimize away unused symbols?